# Weblogic integration and pointbase

Tags: java, weblogic

We have a WebLogic Integration application that integrates applications running in SQL servers through event generators. I understand that WebLogic is shipped with an internal Pointbase database. Is there anyway we can turn off the Pointbase because every now and then this gets corrupted and hence we have to recreate the entire domain and all the associated objects.

Answer (score 2):

Check the setDomainEnv.sh file under $Domain_Home/bin folder. In this file search for "POINTBASE_FLAG" and set its value as false such as

`POINTBASE_FLAG="false"
 export POINTBASE_FLAG`